# Spring Security Login Page

Tags: java, jquery, spring, authentication, spring-security

I developed an application that uses Spring Security's default login page. However I want to implement my own login page. I will put a login.html instead of a jsp page. I want to use JQuery for it. I examined many examples but couldn't achieve. I am new to Spring and Spring Security, I use Spring Security 3. 
 Any ideas which steps I should follow?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make a login page with `plain HTML + jQuery + Spring Security`, too. Have you figured out how to include the Spring Security's built-in support for CSRF.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are four requirements for a custom login page in Spring Security:

1. There is an input field named `j_username` which will contain the name used for the authentication credentials.
2. There is an input field named `j_password` which will contain the password used for the authentication credentials.
3. The url to which these values are `POST`ed matches the url defined in the `login-processing-url` attribute of the `form-login` element in your Spring Security configuration.
4. The location of the custom login form must be specified in the `login-page` attribute of the `form-login` element in your Spring Security configuration.

**Login.html**

```html
    <body>
      <form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
        <label for="username">User Name:</label>
        <input id="username" name="j_username" type="text"/>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
      </form>
    </body>
```

**Spring Security Configuration File**

```xml
    <http use-expressions="true">
      <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
      <form-login
        login-page="/login.html"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.action"
        authentication-failure-url="/login_error.html"
        default-target-url="/home.html"
        always-use-default-target="true"/>
    </http>
```

Comment: Should I write a LoginLogoutController or something like that and how I will set where to redirect if a user logins successfully?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I debugged it with firebug and it says: http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check 302 Moved Temporarily for that redirection problem.

Comment: If you've got the `springSecurityFilterChain` registered correctly in your `web.xml` and it is registered before any of your other filters, it should pick up any request to the url specified by `login-processing-url`.

Comment: After my edits, you can see the `default-target-url` and `always-use-default-target` attributes. These will define whether a user, once authenticated, will be directed to the default page, and if so, what that page is. If `always-use-default-target` is false, the user should be redirected to whatever page they were originally trying to reach.

Comment: What is <intercept-url pattern="/login*"/> for without an access attribute? I still get the same result but I will check my code again.

Comment: There is a post here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?99583-Error-302-moved-temporarily-j_spring_security_check It says: "As a result, I have had to create custom authentication filter by extending the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in spring security 3.0.5." I didn't write any filter, should I? This problem is so important for me, thanks for your helps.

Comment: @kamaci: sorry about the missing `access` attribute in the `intercept-url` element, I've fixed it.

Comment: @kamaci: I'm using a stand-alone login page and have never had to implement my own custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. I've also never seen this `302` issue either...

Comment: @kamaci: also notice that the access rules that I am using for the intercept-urls require the `use-expressions` attribute on the `http` element.

Comment: I fixed that UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and 302 error issue, thanks for your help and voting up. What is that access url for and are isAnonymous and isFullyAuthenticated methods Spring Security's special methods or should I implement them?

Comment: I found a document here that explains is: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html so why you added them instead of filters="none" or access="ROLE_USER", does they do the same thing or not?

Comment: @kamaci: The `intercept-url` elements represent resources/urls protected by the Spring Security filters. The `pattern` attributes specify the paths which are protected. Using `none` in the `filters` attribute will make the Spring Security filter ignore requests for those resources. The `access` attribute values I'm using are expressions provided by Spring Security. They are enabled by using `use-expressions = "true"` in the `http` element.

Comment: I think use-expressions for to allow complicated boolean logic?

Comment: @kamaci: if you're still interested this is a good article on how to configure a custom form based login http://codehustler.org/blog/spring-security-form-login-tutorial/

Comment: @RyanRansford How to leverage the `Spring Security` built-in `CSRF` function? Do I need to manually place a `hidden` input with empty value? Can Spring Security properly fill-in the token?

Comment: `The url to which these values are POST` saved my life.... I was struggling because my form is `GET`...

Answer (score 6):

I have been working for a couple of days on implementing spring security in my project and the configuration that finally did it was the following:

**spring-security.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" use-expressions="true">

    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/login.html"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.action"
        default-target-url="/index.html"
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from smartcaldb.users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, r.authority from smartcaldb.users u, smartcaldb.roles r where u.userid = r.userid and u.username =?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.smartcal.**" />

<!-- setup database connectivity bean -->

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403</location>
</error-page>
```

**login.html**

```
<body>
    <form action="/smartcal/j_spring_security_check.action" method="POST">
        <label for="username">User Name:</label>
        <input id="username" name="j_username" type="text" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </form>
</body>
```

for logout use url - "/{yourAppPathInTheContainer}/j_spring_security_logout"