# Login with Spring security using Ajax

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to work on Ajax based login system using Spring Security and it was working fine, till I got with another requirement where I need to configure `authentication-success-handler`, so as I can do some post processing once user is authenticated by Spring security.

Earlier I was not using `<form-login/>` for showing Login page.My Login section is a drop down and part of header section which is common for entire application.

This is how I am trying to configure Spring security

```
<http pattern="/customer/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="customerAuthenticationManager">
<!--<http pattern="/customer/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">-->
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/logon.html*" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/denied.html" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/customer" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/*.html" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/*/*.html" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />

<form-login login-processing-url="/customer/logon.html" login-page="/shop/home.html" 
authentication-success-handler-ref="webshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<logout invalidate-session="true" 
   logout-success-url="/customer/home.html" 
    logout-url="/customer/j_spring_security_logout" />
 <access-denied-handler error-page="/customer/denied.html"/>
    </http>
```

With these configuration, when ever I am clicking on login button with correct credentials, i am getting HTTP 302 error

```
http://localhost:8080/shop/customer/logon.html 302 found
```

Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong?

```
<form id="login" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" size="30" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
</form>
```

### Ajax Code

```
 var data = $(this).serializeObject();
  $.ajax({
  'type': 'POST',
  'url': "<c:url value="/customer/logon.html"/>",
   'contentType': 'application/json',
    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
     'dataType': 'json',
....
}}:
```

### Login Section

```
 Authentication authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(customer.getUserName(), customer.getPassword());
   try {
       Authentication authentication = customerAuthenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        resp.setStatus(AjaxResponse.RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESS);
           } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {

            resp.setStatus(AjaxResponse.RESPONSE_STATUS_FAIURE);
   }
```

Any inputs? With all my efforts, I am still getting 302 and with above configuration, even my `logon.html` controller is not getting called.

My main issue is when I am enabling Spring security using

```
<form-login login-processing-url="/customer/logon.html" login-page="/shop/home.html" 
    authentication-success-handler-ref="webshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

I am getting `302` from `logon.html` and even `logon.html` Controller is not being triggered (placed debugger on it)

Comment: Do you habe an jsp page for login, that is where login-page  should refers to

Comment: @Ralph:As of now login panel is inside header.jsp, I did some changes to security.xml file  `<form-login login-processing-url="/customer/logon.html" login-page="/shop/home.html" authentication-success-handler-ref="webshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>` but still getting 302 code.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361513/spring-security-login-page

Comment: @jhadesdev: I have already gone through this, but have not got any success.

Comment: Start with a working login sample and take it from there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you don't need a controller, spring security handles all this for you. So drop the controller.

The current problem is due to your JSON based post. This is handled by the normal filter which handles login, but it doesn't see a `j_username` and `j_password` field and as such will redirect (the 302) to the login page (in your case `/shop/home.html`) asking for those fields.

Basically you are posting the data as JSON whereas it simply should be just an ajaxified form post. This allows you to write a simple `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` which simply returns a 401 or a 200 status-code (and maybe a body) when things are ok.

Changing your ajax submit to something like this should make things work.

```
var data = $(this).serializeObject();
$.ajax({
    'type': $(this).action,
    'url': $(this).target,
    'data': data
}):
```

This should create a ajax form post. Might be that you need a call to `preventDefault()` in the surrounding method to stop the form from actual posting.

Comment: So in that case what should be the action URL?

Comment: I am still having same issue, getting 404 error.Have a look at following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661872/filterchainproxy-j-spring-security-check-has-no-matching-filters

Comment: If you get a 404 it means the url isn't correct and you simply call the wrong URL.

Comment: can u clearify use of this... im new to javascript and ajax

Answer (score 1):

With the login form that is currently posted it cannot work, as a form like this is needed:

```
<body>
  <form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
    <input id="username" name="j_username" type="text"/>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

The post needs to be done j_spring_security_check, and username and password need to be suplied in fields j_username and j_password, otherwise it won't work.

I think you are getting a redirect to a login page.

You can see where the redirect is going with the chrome debugger or firebug if using firefox.

To approach this first get the rest of the config working with the default login page generated by spring security, by removing login-page="/customer/logon.html".

Once this works you can add back the custom login page, but it needs to have the elements above.

Also I believe you are trying to post a JSTL tag  via ajax to the server? If it's true it won't work, otherwise can you edit the question.

Try it step by step by first using the default login page, then with an ajax request with hardcoded values just for testing and then when this works with a custom login page.

Comment: you mean that It should be `j_username` and password with same action?

Answer (score -2):

response code 302 is not an error indication. It's a way of performing a redirection.
as you have not shared your webshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler code.

But i am pretty much sure you are redirecting the request to some specified resource after processing some certain condition. so just check your header and get the URL of redirection.
and then redirect with javascript code.

An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the Location header field.

For an example -

Client request:

---

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1

Host: www.example.com

---

Server response:

---

HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/

so along with this error code you are getting http://www.iana.org/domains/example/ url where your authenticationSuccessHandler want you to redirect so redirect it through javascript code.

Comment: my success handler is not even getting called, I have placed debugger on login.html also, but nothing is being triggered