# FilterChainProxy: /j_spring_security_check has no matching filters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring security default login mechanism and this is what I have configured in `security.xml` file

```
<http pattern="/customer/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="customerAuthenticationManager">
<intercept-url pattern="/customer" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/*.html" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/*/*.html" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/shop/customer/logon.html*" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/shop/customer/denied.html" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>

<form-login login-processing-url="/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/shop/home.html"
   authentication-success-handler-ref="webshopAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
/>
<logout invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/customer/home.html" 
            logout-url="/customer/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/customer/denied.html"/>
</http>
```

This is how I have configured spring security in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <filter-class>
   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
 </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And this is how I am submitting my form using ajax

```
 var data = $(this).serializeObject();
            $.ajax({
                'type': "POST",
                'url': "<c:url value="/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check"/>",
                'data': data,
               'success': function(result) {
             }
            });
   return false;
 });
```

But no authentication is getting triggered and I am getting `404` error, but have seen following information in console

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check'; against '/admin/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check'; against '/customer/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check'; against '/shop/services/private/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: /shop/customer/j_spring_security_check has no matching filters
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/sm-shop/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Looking up handler method for path /shop/customer/j_spring_security_check
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/resources/img/loading.gif'; against '/admin/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/resources/img/loading.gif'; against '/customer/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/resources/img/loading.gif'; against '/shop/services/private/**'

....

DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Did not find handler method for [/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check]
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sm-shop/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

any idea?

Comment: Yuor http element doesn't apply to `/shop/customer` due to the `pattern="/customer/**"` on the http element. If you have multiple elements please post the full configuration, only with snippets we cannot help you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I will post additional information

Comment: The logging is quite clear. Nothing matches. No URL pattern matches your `/shop/customer` so spring security never sees your login attempt.

Comment: @M.Deinum: can you please post your comment as answer, I will mark it as accepted.Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 3):

- Are you having multiple `http` configurations? If not, you do not need to specify `<http pattern="/customer/**"...>`.
- If you have multiple `http` configuration sections and using Spring Security 3.1+, from the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-http-pattern):

> Defining a pattern for the http element controls the requests which
>   will be filtered through the list of filters which it defines.
>   
>   This means that you should define multiple security filters with the same pattern so that Spring will match them separately. And, if no pattern is defined for `http`, it defaults to `/*` which you've defined in your `web.xml`. So, if you do not have a specific restriction, it may be easier to first test if this work for you with all `http` configuration in one element and then extend to multiple ones.

- Try to configure *from most specific to more general patterns*.
- Try to use to use wildcard option towards the end of the configuration.
- And I believe the one with `pattern="/customer/*/*.html"` should be `pattern="/customer/**/*.html"`. It is missing one `*`.

So based on what I said:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="customerAuthenticationManager">
<intercept-url pattern="/shop/customer/logon.html*" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/shop/customer/denied.html" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/shop/customer/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/customer" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
// XXX: bring in also your /admin configuration before the wildcards
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/*.html" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/**/*.html" access="hasRole('AUTH_CUSTOMER')" />
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even with suggested changes, I am facing same issue :(