# Spring Security Authentication does not work with AngularJS (302)

Tags: angularjs, authentication, spring-security

I implemented LDAP authentication with Spring Security. Tested with the default formLogin, and it works. Here is my security config using Spring Boot:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login");
}
```

Now I want to use AngularJS to login. Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709893/how-to-use-angularjs-login-to-spring-security), I wrote the following service and controller in AngularJS to post username and password to Spring Security:

```
//service.js
authApp.factory("loginFactory", function ($http) {
    return{
        login: function(username, password) {
            var data = "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&submit=Login";
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
                data: data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            });  
        }
    }   
});

//controller
authApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'loginFactory', function($scope, $location, loginFactory){
    $scope.authenticate = function() {
        loginFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $location.path('/home');
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}]);
```

When I debug it, it gets to `errorCallBack` function. However the response seems to be null since it displays `Object {data: null, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""}` in the console. When I look at "network" tab in Chrome, there are a bunch of 302 for login.

Checked the server side log (started the application as Spring Boot App within Spring Tool Suite), no record for any post request. If I just type in "http://localhost:8080/login" at least in STS console, it will show a request has been received. Post with following curl command also works.

```
curl -X POST -c cookies -L 'http://localhost:8080/login' -d'username=ddd&password=xxxyyyzzz'
```

Why didn't the server receive the request?

Comment: your angularjs code seems to be good. Try to use a tool to send the authentication post request to server and see what is the answer. I don't think it is an angular problem.

Comment: @BillBilal What tool are you referring to? I used curl to send the authentication and it works without any problem (see my command in the post)

Comment: Honestly I don't see what is the problem.

Comment: @BillBilal What does `&submit=Login` do?

Comment: Nothing, you can remove it. Spring security will look for username and password like this : request.getParameter("username") and request.getParameter("password").

Comment: its not work with me. just got an error while calling to controller