# Spring authentication handling ajax request and default login page

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-security

So, I'm living the spring security java config dream(?) having ditched the xml and all is working smoothly - except;

I'm logging in and out via ajax requests

eg:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/sg/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
         .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400*30) // 30 days
        .and().formLogin().successForwardUrl("/loginSuccessAjax.html").failureForwardUrl("/UnsuccessfulLoginAjax")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/getFrontPage.html");
    }
```

but if an **AccessDeniedException** is thrown when an unauthenticated user attempts to access a secured url the default spring login page is shown whereas I would like the /getFrontPage.html to be displayed.

Versions

Spring Security 4.1.0.RELEASE
Spring 4.2.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. I'm posting it in the hope it may save others some pain.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')")
    .antMatchers("/sg/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
     .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400*30) // 30 days
    .and().formLogin().successForwardUrl("/loginSuccessAjax.html").failureForwardUrl("/UnsuccessfulLoginAjax")
     .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);



}
```

And the authenticationEntryPoint you'll need to auto-wire in

```
@Component
public class HttpAuthenticationPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/getFrontPage.html");

    }
}
```

ATB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write controller for it?

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "getFrontPage.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accesssDenied(Principal user) {
        return "getFrontPage.html";
    }
}
```

Also you should check [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/customize-http-403-access-denied-page-in-spring-security/).

Comment: Hi Gennady, spring security is internally handling the exception and forwarding onto the default login page. If I attempt to specify a bespoke login page, with formlogin().loginpage(..) the ajax handling is broken. I have also tried to catch and handle the exception with a global exception handler, with no success.

Comment: @jaseFace, are you sure that you wrote correct ajax? If you write your own login page with formlogin().loginpage(..) you should specify correct form's fields names. If all is ok it should work. Also for ajax check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538619/login-with-spring-security-using-ajax).