# Spring Security with Ajax Based role login.

Tags: ajax, security

I am working On e-commerce project, In my project applying basic spring security role based(form-based) but i need ajax based role login (pop-up). without using redirect strategy because every time it goes to landing page.

case 1: i want below link type login.
https://www.flipkart.com/checkout/init

case 2: if my login is success. i will be on the same page.but in role based 
(success handler) navigating to the corresponding role-dashboard.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you want and have done? Now it seems like you want someone to code this for you?

Comment: First of all thanks. I am using spring-security-role (form-based) but now i want ajax based login. i need reference link.  present code look like this http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-role-based-login-example/

Comment: i found one link for ajax  with Spring Security 2002229_SpringSecurityAjaxDemo.zip but how to identify the role. in my project have admin,customer, manafacturer role. how to navigatie to corresponding to dash boards.

Comment: i found one more link stack overflow is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538619/login-with-spring-security-using-ajax but its not clear to me. give me reference link.