# How can I check what roles @PreAuthorize is looking at?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have some Spring Controller methods that I had, at first, secured with the @Secured notation

```
@Secured("Role_Admin")
public void dummyMethod(HttpServletRequest request) ...
```

Which would recognize the role fine, or reject if the user did not have the role (as expected). However, I tried switching to use the @PreAuthorize annotation, and now EVERYTHING is getting denied.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Role_Admin')")
public void dummyMethod(HttpServletRequest request) ...
```

If I remove the @PreAuthorize annotation, and do something, say

```
request.isUserInRole("Role_Admin")
```

that will return true. If I leave in the annotation, and then check the user's roles
in the access denied handler, I can see the 'Role_Admin' authority is granted to the user.

So I'm not exactly sure what roles/authorities the code behind @PreAuthorize is checking. Does anybody know what spring security classes I can check?

**EDIT**

I'm using Java to configure everything. So it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfigurator extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration { ...
```

In my reply to an answer below, the reason I'm switching from @Secured is because it's not kicking off my AccessDeniedHandler. If I could force it to do so, I'd stick with it. @PreAuthorize does kick off the handler.

**EDIT2**

As pointed out by Andrei, I tried defining this in my configuration. It did not make a difference though.

```
@Bean
public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver() {
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

    resolver.setExcludedExceptions(AccessDeniedException.class);

    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "p404");
    mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
    mappings.put("org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException", "dataAccessFailure");

    resolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings);

    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your security config xml?

Comment: Most probably, you've seen [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171882/spring-security-ignoring-access-denied-handler-with-method-level-security) but I thought I'd share it.

Comment: Saw that. I did try adding something to my configuration, but the ExceptionHandler would still grab the exception instead of the AccessDeniedHandler. Adding the configuration to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you wanting to use `@PreAuthorize` as opposed to `@Secured`? I imagine that your `@PreAuthorize` is failing because you haven't set your http security to use expressions:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
```

I imagine if you do this then it won't matter which version you use. I seem to remember one of the Spring developers who posts on SO saying that `@Secured` is the preferred method because it is newer than `@PreAuthorize` or some such reason. I suspect that `@Secured` is more self-contained and doesn't interact with as many Spring components. If this doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: When I use the Secure annotation, the access denied exceptions are not picked up by my AccessDeniedHandler. PreAuthorize annotation does send the expections to the handler. If I could get the Secure annotation to kick off the AccessDeniedHandler, that would be ideal. Nothing I've tried has worked though. I'll post my config in the question.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I'm 90% sure that if the user fails with `@Secured` you just get a 401 back to the browser without touching the `AccessDeniedHandler`. If you want to intercept either pre or post handle authentication events, look into extending `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`