# Spring Security, Spring MVC, PreAuthorise annotation and exception handling

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-cas

I'm struggling with Spring Security and exception handling.

I have the following exception handler configured in my servlet-context:

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="defaultErrorView" value="/errors/general-error"/>
        <property name="defaultStatusCode" value="500" />
        <property name="warnLogCategory" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"/>
    </bean>
```

This catches any uncaught exceptions, and shows a general error page.

I also have Spring Security configured using a CAS single sign on server.  If in my Security configuration I have the following:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
```

If an unauthenticated user visits "/secure", they are correctly redirected to login, then they return and can view the page.

I'd prefer to use `PreAuthorise()` annotations on the MVC methods, rather than having to define the URLs manually.  So instead, if I have the following annotation:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @RequestMapping("/secure")
    public String displaySecurePage(
...
}
```

The redirect to the CAS SSO server doesn't happen, and Spring simply displays the general error page, with an Exception `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied`

Why is there a difference between the two ways of defining the access permissions, and how can I use the `PreAuthorise` annotation with Spring correctly directing an unauthenticated user to login, *and* still have a exception handler to catch other exceptions?

Comment: do you set pre-post-annotations="enabled" in your <sec:global-method-security tag> tag? This will enables using @PreAuthorize and other related tags.

Comment: Yes - the "PreAuthorize" tags work otherwise "AccessDenied" wouldn't get thrown at all.  The problem is with having a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver bean and using the annotations

Comment: I found the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21172182/1116197  This is such a simple thing to be trying to do and it's taken me several hours of searching.  Spring is so frustrating!!