# ErrorHandling in Spring Security for @PreAuthorize AccessDeniedException returns 500 rather then 401

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

Dear all I like to customize the error handling in a Spring 4 Rest application so it should return a HTTP Code 401 rather a Server Error 500 in case the check in @PreAuthorize annotation in my controller fails.

I have an own AuthenticationEntryPoint and AuthenticationFailureHandler registered which its commence / error handling methods returns a 401. This works fine for my JWT authentication but in case of a failed @PreAuthorize check with "AccessDeniedException" these error methods get never called and spring returns a server error 500.

How can I customize that? Looks like I missed something? Thanks for any hints in advance.

Here my AuthenticationEntryPoint class:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException, ServletException {       
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + authException.getMessage() + "\" }");
   }
}
```

Here my AuthenticationFailureHandler:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.sendError(401, (new StringBuilder()).append("Authentication Failed: ").append(exception.getMessage()).toString());
    }
}
```

Here my spring security configuration

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<security:http  pattern="/api/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"  >
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"   />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="jwtAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="ch.megloff.common.webservice.jwt.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

<bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" class="ch.megloff.common.webservice.jwt.JWTAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"><value>/api/**</value></constructor-arg>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></property>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="jwtAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="jwtAuthenticationProvider" class="ch.megloff.common.webservice.jwt.JWTAuthenticationProvider" />
<bean id="jwtAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="ch.megloff.common.webservice.jwt.JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
```

Here my rest controller class

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
   @RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers(HttpServletRequest request,    HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Fetching all Users");
    List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
    if(users.isEmpty()){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here the stack trace from the server when @PreAuthorize check in the annotation fails:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myusers] in context with path    [/JWTAuthenticationExample] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied] with root cause
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at ch.megloff.myusers.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$635caa86.listAllUsers(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.forward(RequestWrapper.java:154)
at ch.megloff.common.webservice.jwt.JWTAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(JWTAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:23)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:326)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the discussion of another post (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171882/spring-security-ignoring-access-denied-handler-with-method-level-security)) I came to the conclusion that the error handling for @PreAuthorize and authentication uses different concepts. The only way is to use in spring 3.2 the new concept of a [generic error handler](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) with @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler annotation. So you can reuse the error handler class.

Example

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException, ServletException {    
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + authException.getMessage() + "\" }");
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(value = { AccessDeniedException.class })
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException ex ) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + ex.getMessage() + "\" }");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also do this by setting error in response like 'response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());'

Comment: The issue is still not fixed in 2018

Comment: Not fixed even in 2020